# Join with subquery

Tags: java, mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have 4 tables

```
1. members(id, name, milk_no, ...)
2. collections(id, member_id, amount, date, ...)
3. credit_payment_transaction(id, member_id, amount, date, ...)
4. deductions(id, member_id, amount, date, ...)
```

I am trying to come up with a query that will return for each member.

```
milk_no | totalDeduction  | totalStore | totalCollection
```

The result should return only member with atleast one of `totalDeduction  | totalStore | totalCollection`

This is what i have come up with

```
SELECT members.milk_no, memberCollections.totalCollection, stores.totalStore, memberDeductions.totalDeduction
FROM members
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalCollection, member_id 
    FROM collections 
    GROUP BY member_id) AS memberCollections
    ON memberCollections.member_id = members.id
    
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalStore, member_id 
    FROM credit_payment_transaction 
    GROUP BY member_id) AS stores
    ON stores.member_id = members.id        
    
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalDeduction, member_id 
    FROM deductions 
    GROUP BY member_id) AS memberDeductions
    ON memberDeductions.member_id = members.id
```

The above query return this

[image]

The problem with this result is, it includes unwanted data(the ones with 3 nulls). When i change to `RIGHT JOIN` no result is returned at all.

Comment: First read why join exist and and its usage. It would solve your issue. If you don't want null and duplicate values use Inner join. :)

Comment: Left joins are correct, because if you use inner join, then if a member is missing from one table, then that member will be missing from the whole result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a WHERE clause at the bottom of your query:

```
WHERE totalCollection IS NOT NULL OR totalStore IS NOT NULL OR totalDeduction IS NOT NULL
```

You can simplify your query like this:

```
SELECT m.id, SUM(c.amount) AS totalCollection, SUM(cpt.amount) AS totalStore, SUM(d.amount) AS totalDeduction
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN collections c ON m.id = c.member_id
LEFT JOIN credit_payment_transaction cpt ON m.id = cpt.member_id
LEFT JOIN deductions d ON m.id = d.member_id
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING SUM(c.amount) > 0 OR  SUM(cpt.amount) > 0 OR SUM(d.amount) > 0
```

Also this query will eliminate the member duplications

Comment: Both works fine... Another observation is that the solution not using subquery takes half the it's alternative with subquery takes.